# Disable JavaScript for a RSpecTest

Tags: rspec-rails

I want to disable javascript for a rspec test.

Ex

```
it '[SP01/UC18/TC25] title error for 31 letters' do

  #=> Disable javascript (because text box is already validated by JS to max input 30     characters)
     fill_in('title', :with => 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA')
  #=> Enable javascript (because I want to track the error messages)
     click_button 'submit'
     page.should have_content 'error in title'
     page.should have_content 'please enter less than 30 characters'

end
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer

```
describe '[SP01/UC25] title error for 31 letters', :js => false, :type => :request do
end
```

Comment: Hope this will help to someone